# React-Native AsyncStorage returna null

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

Boa estou com um problema quando vou salvar alguns dados no AsyncStorage, quando vou retornar ele vem nulo.

**salvar :**

```
export const listarRecados = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        firebase.database().ref('/Recados/')
          .on('value', recados => {
              var recado = {};
              $.forEach(recados.val(), (recados, recID) => {
                    firebase.database().ref('/Equipe/').child(recados.enviadoPorId)
                    .once('value', equipe => {
                        enviadoPor = equipe.val()
                        recado[recID] = {...recados, recID, ...enviadoPor}
                    })
              })
              AsyncStorage.setItem('Recados', JSON.stringify(recado));
              dispatch({ type: LISTAR_RECADOS, payload: recado })
          })
     }
};
```

**retorno:**

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('Recados', (erro, resultado) => {
            console.log(">>>", resultado)
        });
```

ele retorna nulo

Comment: Aparentemente está tudo correto, o que acontece quando você reexecuta este código, continua retornando null ? Segundo a documentação do React Native, getItem() retorna null no callback quando não há valor para aquela chave

Comment: Pedro, então por alguma razão o setItem não esta salvado sera que tem alguma coisa errada porque antes ele aparecia normal agora parou depois que eu adicionei a busca da equipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema acontece por que firebase.database().ref('/Equipe/').child é uma chamada assíncrona. Quando você chama AsyncStorage.setItem seu objeto recado ainda não foi preenchido.

Você precisa garantir que o .once foi chamado antes de fazer o setItem. Se não estivesse dentro de um forEach, o AsyncStorage.setItem poderia estar dentro do .once, mas nesse caso ele vai chamar repetidas vezes. Para evitar essa chamada repetida você pode usar o index do forEach para só salvar no último item. Ficaria +- assim:

```
export const listarRecados = () => {
return dispatch => {
    firebase.database().ref('/Recados/')
      .on('value', recados => {
          var recado = {};
          $.forEach(recados.val(), (recados, recID) => {
                firebase.database().ref('/Equipe/').child(recados.enviadoPorId)
                .once('value', equipe => {
                    enviadoPor = equipe.val()
                    recado[recID] = {...recados, recID, ...enviadoPor}
                    if(recID==recados.val().length){
                        AsyncStorage.setItem('Recados', JSON.stringify(recado));
                        dispatch({ type: LISTAR_RECADOS, payload: recado })
                     }
                })
          })
      })
 }
```

};